# Identifying components in a component-based game engine

Tags: architecture, components

I have read a lot of articles on the web regarding Component-Based Game Architecture, so I've decided to implement a simple system to test this architecture out.

I have implemented a generic game node, which is host to nothing but a basic list of components and a few methods for adding and removing such components. I also have a list of messages belonging to a certain node, to facilitate communication between them.

The example just has bots which own guns (there are basic 'gun' guns as well as derived types with different stats and so on) and they shoot each other and print the outcome to the console. Whenever one of them shoots the other, a message is posted in the latter's list with the MSG_SHOT code and the damage amount as an argument. This works OK.

However, I have decided to add 'scopes' to some guns, doubling their damage. However, I couldn't really find a way for a weapon to check if one of its children is a scope, without actually iterating through them. There are a few basic solutions, but I'm aiming towards a generic one (not just adding a 'scope' field to the gun and leave it null if it has no scope). What if I wanted to possibly attach a myriad of other gizmos with various effects to the gun? How would I be able to make them affect the 'shoot' method of my gun component?

Should I just iterate through all the guns' children when 'shoot' is called and see if they're capable of affecting the gunshot? I don't think relying on the component name would be any good. Maybe I want a certain effect when any scope is available, but a fancy one for a particular kind of scope.

Thanks in advance for any pointers, and yes, I've read tons of articles/ questions before posting this, and I'm still, sadly, confused... :(

Comment: I added a simple query function that searches a node's trees for a certain type, and returns the first result or null otherwise. Works pretty good so far. Other than that, the message system seems to work ok. The send message function of a node returns a result generic object if a receiver for that project is located, or null otherwise. Are there any significant problems with this interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the details you have given me of your setup this is what I've got but please expand if it sounds like I misunderstood your layout.

The calculations pertinent to an object should be done within that object.

So to...''Should I just iterate through all the guns' children when 'shoot' is called and see if they're capable of affecting the gunshot' ...yes, since the scope affects the damage output of the gun that work should be done on the gun side before the message is sent.  I would see it setup in some kind of 'CalcDamageDelt' in which information is passed from the gun to each of its attachments to come up with the guns total output damage.

Once the guns output is calculated the result would be packaged up and sent to the receiver.  The receiver would then calculate any resistance (armor whatever) to the damage and apply the result.

From you comment it sounds like this is the route you went, but with a more singular approach (return null or not) rather than a boarder 'apply your affect to my damage'.  So I think you are going in a good direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :D Well not really, the return can send back anything, such as a String, like "Hey, you hit me" or a status object or anything. Should I worry about the extra overhead of these checks? What if the gun is really complex, with lots of children, and I have to loop over ALL of them just to check for, say, a scope? Wouldn't that affect my game's performance? In most 'regular', direct hierarchy approaches this would basically just be a O(1) operation such as if(scope != null) { ... }

Comment: Okay, another practicality problem - unit objects always have a 'stats' node, a box2d one and a graphical sprite one. These fields need quite a lot of interaction and querying, would it be bad practice to just add references to them? Oh, and another question now arises - should I differentiate between 'just components' and actual entities? Like applying more lenient rules to entities such as the 'unit' and 'player' objects, allowing things like direct references apart from the restrictive 'children' array?

Comment: I guess what I was saying about the scope part is that I would try and keep any calculations that require a scope within the gun component.  Looping through even 100 things doesn't take long as long as it is on a trigger calculation and not just a per frame check.  If you need external items to check for a scope then I would go with your approach, perhaps have the gun know it can have a scope and cache the result.

Comment: As far as references go I think they work out fine, the goal is to keep the logic and the data modular, so you can unplug a sprite and replace it with a model and go on your way.  As long as you don't break that idea and just use the reference to save you from constantly doing a name lookup.  I find in practice I alway move in between 'the perfectly setup engine' and 'code that will run fast enough'.  So if you are trying to make something and not just a demo a few exceptions are bound to come up.

Comment: Ah, I understand! Thank you very much. I've realized I was over-purifying the concept. I now have some basic classes such as Unit and so on that contain direct references to basic things like a renderable node (a sprite so far), a physics one (box2D wrapper) and so on. I see that this is how the concept should be implemented. I now have modular objects I can attach to anything, no complex class hierarchy but also a speedy and non-confusing way of communication between said objects. Thanks again!